# Vs Code: Move selected file to new tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut

For example: I have 2 files opened, I usually use "ctrl + tab" to move between them. And when i need to move one file into new tab I press "ctrl + 2" to open new tab and move file with mouse. So is there a shortcut in VS Code to do the same process?

Comment: have you tried `Split Editor Right` `Ctrl+Backslash`

Comment: @rioV8 It's almost what i need. I want to move, in your case it duplicates

Comment: then do `Ctrl+1 Ctrl+W Ctrl+2`, you can group these commands with `multi-command` under a new key binding

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+RightArrow`, a.k.a. "View: Move Editor into Right Group" maybe

Comment: Search for "Move Editor Group" in the Keyboard Shortcuts editor to see all the options for moving the current editor into various groups.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+Alt+RightArrow` on Windows

`Ctrl+Command+RightArrow` on Mac